# Game Theory - Raising Competing Firm's Marginal Cost

Tags: game-theory

Suppose two firms selling an identical product engage in Cournot competition. There are 100 potential customers and the industry demand is 100 − p. Firms choose quantities qi ∈ [0, 50], which leads to a price that equalizes supply and demand. Firms maximize their profits. This applies to problem below.

Raising rival’s costs:
Suppose that firm 1 can spend x dollars to increase the other firm’s marginal cost to $20 (leaving its own marginal cost unchanged). Then, given the new costs, the firms choose their quantities simultaneously. What is the most money (i.e., the largest X), that firm 1 would be willing to spend on this?

Comment: This seems like a homework question.  What have you tried?

Comment: I created a maximization problem with profits(firm 1) = (100-q1-q2)q1-10q1-x and profits(firm 2)= (100-q1-q2)q2-20q2 and solved for q2 and plugged into q1 but it got messy so not sure if that's the way to go.